# In Netty 4, what's the difference between ctx.close and ctx.channel.close?

Tags: netty

Is there any difference? Is `ctx.close` just a shorter version of `ctx.channel.close`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's say we have three handlers in the pipeline, and they all intercept the `close()` operation, and calls `ctx.close()` in it.

```
ChannelPipeline p = ...;
p.addLast("A", new SomeHandler());
p.addLast("B", new SomeHandler());
p.addLast("C", new SomeHandler());
...

public class SomeHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void close(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise) {
        ctx.close(promise);
    }
}
```

- `Channel.close()` will trigger `C.close()`, `B.close()`, `A.close()`, and then close the channel.
- `ChannelPipeline.context("C").close()` will trigger `B.close()`, `A.close()`, and then close the channel.
- `ChannelPipeline.context("B").close()` will trigger `A.close()`, and then close the channel.
- `ChannelPipeline.context("A").close()` will close the channel. No handlers will be called.

So, when you should use `Channel.close()` and `ChannelHandlerContext.close()`?  The rule of thumb is:

- If you are writing a `ChannelHandler` and wanna close the channel in the handler, call `ctx.close()`.
- If you are closing the channel from outside the handler (e.g. you have a background thread which is not an I/O thread, and you want to close the connection from that thread.)

Comment: In general, ctx.channel.close should be used? Can you give examples where ctx.close should be used?

Comment: In general you can use ctx.close() when you know the "later" ChannelHandler's in the ChannelPipeline not care about the close event.

Comment: [ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html) does not have a close() method, so we cannot `@Override` and the bullet points don't make sense to me. @trustin am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for reporting. It should be `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 29):

ctx.close() starts to flow through the ChannelPipeline from the point of the ChannelHandlerContext while ctx.channel().close() will start from the tail of the ChannelPipeline all the time.