# Use of ctx.read() vs. ctx.channel.read() in Netty Examples

Tags: java, netty

Netty's pipelining (i.e. `ctx.foo()` vs `ctx.channel.foo()`) has been explained twice before on StackOverflow:

1. [Any difference between ctx.write() and ctx.channel().write() in netty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366418/any-difference-between-ctx-write-and-ctx-channel-write-in-netty)
2. [In Netty 4, what's the difference between ctx.close and ctx.channel.close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240981/in-netty-4-whats-the-difference-between-ctx-close-and-ctx-channel-close)

However, I don't understand the intuition behind Netty's examples of when to use the different approaches:

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.read(); // <----- HERE
}

public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    inboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                ctx.channel().read(); // <----- HERE
            } else {
                future.channel().close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**[View source on GitHub](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyBackendHandler.java#L34-L43)**

---

Why use the 'from this handler down' style `read` in the `channelActive` handler of the proxy impl, but use the 'from the top' style `read` in `channelRead`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `ChannelHandlerContext.read()` it will start from the point in the `ChannelPipeline` where the `ChannelHandler`is located. When you use `Channel.read()` it will start from the tail of the `ChannelPipeline` and so need to traverse the whole `ChannelPipeline` in worse cast.

The reason why this example use `ctx.read()` in `channelActive(...)` but `channel.read()` in the `ChannelFutureListener` is because the `ChannelFutureListener` is not part of a `ChannelHandler` and so it needs to start at the tail of the `ChannelPipeline`. Also note the the `Channel`s are different here.

Comment: I still don't fully understand this. What exactly is being called on the subsequent handlers when you say "it will start from the point in the pipeline where the handler is located." AFAIK when you call `.read()` all you're doing is asking the socket to read some data... then if/when the data arrives, the `channelRead` will be triggered at the _start_ of the pipeline anyway. Or when you call `ctx.read()`, do the previous handlers not receive any data if/when data arrives?

Comment: If you have `ChannelOutboundHandler` in your `ChannelPipeline` these have `read(...)` callbacks that will be triggered by the `read()` operation and may do something (for example like just discard it).